# WordPress debug messages not displaying

Tags: plugin-development, errors, debug, wp-debug

WordPress is not displaying any errors / debug messages, even though I double- and triple-checked every setting.

**In php.ini, I have**

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
track_errors = On`

**In wp-config.php, I have:**

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);`

Still, no errors are displayed at all. I verified that it is not a general PHP issue by testing it with an erroneous php file, like this: `<?php askdjh akjdsh ?>`. The error was displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a plugin (wp-spamfree), which simply set `error_reporting(0)`.

So if anyone has the same problem, my advice is to search your whole `wp-content/plugins` directory for words like `error_reporting`, `display_errors` and similar to find out if any of your plugins tamper with these settings.

You can either disable these plugins, or fix it yourself for now and let the developers know that they should not do this.

**Fixes:**

1. One way to fix this is to simply remove the unwanted `error_reporting(0)`.
2. However, if you want to make sure that the plugin won't display any    errors (which I think is stupid), another way would be to replace    `error_reporting(0)` with `$errlvl = error_reporting(0);`.

   This will save your current, desired error reporting level in `$errlvl`. The function will be executed with `error_reporting = 0`. At the end of the function you can then reset it back to the previous, desired level by calling `error_reporting($errlvl);`.

Comment: .... or better, not to use plugin of anyone that writes this kind of code to hide error :(

Comment: Yeah... I think I'll drop that addon anyway. I'm not even sure whether it's still alive or not. Most of the forum posts on wordpress.org are pretty old (1+ years) and say it's no longer working. However, the plugin page states that it was updated 4 months ago. *shrug*